# recvfrom read wrong ethernet address from raw socket

Tags: android, c, sockets

I tried to use libpcap for sniff packets,
but sometimes it give me a wrong ethernet header.

then i tried to use a simpler program to debug this issue, the behaviour is the same.

then i moved the libpcap into my program, performing the same syscall as libpcap were do on my target platform ( android arm linux ), and the result is unchanged.

i tried to retrieve the interface index using another socket rather then the main one.
this time things get a little better, wrong packets were drastically reduced. but sometimes them still appear.

program source: http://pastebin.com/K0JZgtiK

sample output: http://pastebin.com/zsg0MZZF

i've also opened an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81370) on the android bug tracker.

i've also tried to fork instead of using threads, but nothing changes.

<s>but having two distinct programs, one that send and one that sniff, works correctly.</s>

thanks in advance for any help, this problem is driving me mad.

#### UPDATE

two different programs, one that send and one that receive, have the same problem.
i didn't figured it out before because the sender was too slow.
probably this issue happens if a packets is sent while recvfrom is reading a previous one.

here the relevant part of nbns.h :

```
#define NBNS_NBSTATREQ_LEN 50
extern uint8_t nbns_nbstat_request[NBNS_NBSTATREQ_LEN];
```

and nbns.c :

```
/**
 * @brief static NetBIOS NBSTAT request.
 * 
 * RFC 1002, Paragraph 4.2.17
 */
uint8_t nbns_nbstat_request[NBNS_NBSTATREQ_LEN] = {
    0x82, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x43, 0x4B, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
    0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
    0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
    0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x21, 0x00, 0x01
};
```

Comment: Although it's possible you are getting the wrong header, it seems more likely that you are getting the right header for a different packet than you expected.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yep, i thought this scenario too.
but the `sockaddr_ll` struct is the same, according to that the packet should be the same.
but i think that you may are right.
studying the wrong bytes, the first 2 are the last 2 of the destination MAC address. followed by `00:00:00:00:AA:AA:03:00:00:00` , the ethernet protocol ( `08:00` if IP ) and the upper layers ( ARP or IP or whatever ). i think that this is a buffer overflow in the kernel, no other answer come into my mind.
thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Could you also add `"nbns.h`? The source could be in the question also, imho that makes it somewhat easier to access and especially more permanent.

Another comment, did I understand correctly, that you get the expected results, if you run two separate processes? I would suggest that hints at a bug in your original code, as opposed to the kernel...

Comment: @thuovila thanks for asking me it again! i made another test and figured out that this problem affect even 2 different processes.
i've also tried to sniff with tcpdump, it get 4 wrong ethernet headers on about 7000 packets. it is certainly a kernel problem. for now a quick solution is to drop packets that does not have my ethernet address in the source address or in the destination one.

Comment: another note, by not printing the packets the error rate drastically reduces, probably the buffer passed to recvfrom is kept inside the kernel for some reason and while you are calling fprintf the sendto/write call overwrite your buffer with the bad data.